# data posting with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a code structure as follows;

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function mmk'.$imageid.' (){

 $(document).on("click", ".like'.$imageid.'", function(){

  $.post("",{pid:$(this).attr("id"),action:"like'.$imageid.'"},function(){


   });

 });
});
</script>

$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$action=$_POST['action'];


if ($action=='like'.$imageid.''){

....//mysql operations//.....

}
```

there is a problem related with infinite scroll because in normal page I can post data to both of variables ($pid and $action). But, in loaded page for more content I can not post data to variables with same code structure.

what should I do to solve this problem? if you help, I would be appreciate

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm condused

Comment: When I click the button, I want to post data called "pid" and "action" to variables in loaded page by infinite scroll.

Comment: Well you need a page to 'post' to: `$.post("your-url-here",...`
You should read up on AJAX

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue on infinite scroll. I think there's nothing to do.